# Autowired injected variable is null

Tags: spring, jsf, autowired

I have a `FacesValidator` class named `UniqueEmailValidator` to determine that the entered email is unique or not.

I need the `userService` variable, so i inject it by spring.

Here is the `UniqueEmailValidator.java` :

```
@FacesValidator("com.obs.bean.uniqueEmailValidator")
@Component
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value == null) {
            return;
        }
        String email = (String) value;
        System.out.println("userService before use: " + userService); // null
        boolean exists = userService.emailExists(email);
        if (exists) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Email already in use", null));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `UserServiceImple.java`:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService<User, Integer>, Serializable {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDao")
private UserDao userDao;

@Transactional()
public boolean emailExists(String value) {
    Query query = userDao.getSession().createQuery("from User where email=?");
    query.setString(0, value);
    if (query.uniqueResult() != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

But the `userService` is `null`, (I get `nullPointerException`)

I have also This lines in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Activates scanning of @Repository and @Service -->
<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>
```

Comment: Looks like JSF is managing the instance of `UniqueEmailValidator` and not Spring, thus you cannot inject any object.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So is there any solution?

Comment: I won't use a validator for this case, as simple as that.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So how you recognize the entered email is unique or not?

Comment: For this specific case, I would set a unique key in database, try to insert and handle the exception for unique key constraint not met. If you still want/need to display a nice message to user for validation, then I would recommend processing this validation in the `action`. It's not the right approach but is what you can do for this case. Also, I would submit a ticket to JSF guys to add support for injection of  CDI/Spring/Guice beans on validators and converters.

Comment: By the way, mkyong has this covered: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/spring-autowired-into-jsf-custom-validator/

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Your link solved my problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable the validator with the tag

```
<f:validator validatorId="validatorId"/>
```

then the validator instance is created by the JSF implementation (by getting the Class and just calling newInstance()), hence it is not recognized as Spring bean and autowiring doesn't work. To get the validator instance as Spring bean, you have to use the binding attribute:

```
<f:validator binding="#{validatorBeanName}"/>
```

In that case, the annotation `@FacesValidator` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use parametrized declaration for your autowired service

```
@Autowired
private UserService<User, Integer> userService;
```

Or try to use @Qualifier and give a name to your service

```
@Service("myService")
public class UserServiceImpl ...
```

...

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myService")
private UserService<User, Integer> userService;
```